# HTML5 Audio Tag JS touchstart event working on iPad, not on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, html5-audio

I have been working on making a wonderful site to play the GoT shame sound when a shame event is published in particle's SSE queue. Currently I have this working great on every device (iPad/Android/Desktop/etc) except for the iPhone.

For mobile devices I am using the `ontouchstart` event to play/pause the audio file so that I can later initiate the JS play method when the shame SSE is seen. When I add in the controls option the sound can be played by pressing play on the phone. Even after that it is unable to be triggered via JS. Any help would be appreciated. See code below

Code: https://gist.github.com/nctiggy/17e87e68dedf8c4c4530

Deployed to site: http://cersei.cfapps.io

Comment: Solved my own problem. I swear I had to post this in order to solve it. Needed to load/play/pause ontouchstart....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own problem:

Needed to run the `load()` method before the initial play/pause at the `ontouchstart` event.

Here is the working code: https://gist.github.com/nctiggy/67edb2df65b10ea28a58

Comment: It says I have to wait 2 days